# My NDK project fails to compile with a CPU architecture-related issue

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Can someone explain why I get this errors please?

```
Build command failed.


Error while executing process C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Mygame\proj.android-studio\app\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Mygame\proj.android-studio\app\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Mygame/proj.android-studio/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Mygame\proj.android-studio\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 APP_PLATFORM=android-10 NDK_MODULE_PATH=C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Mygame/cocos2d;C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Mygame/cocos2d/cocos;C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Mygame/cocos2d/external -j4 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


Android NDK: INTERNAL ERROR: The armeabi ABI should have exactly one `architecture definitions. Found: ''`    
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed. 
*** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
Build command failed.


Error while executing process C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Mygame\proj.android-studio\app\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Mygame\proj.android-studio\app\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Mygame/proj.android-studio/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Mygame\proj.android-studio\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 APP_PLATFORM=android-10 NDK_MODULE_PATH=C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Mygame/cocos2d;C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Mygame/cocos2d/cocos;C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Mygame/cocos2d/external -j4 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

Android NDK: INTERNAL ERROR: The armeabi ABI should have exactly one architecture definitions. Found: ''    
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
*** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

I leave here a screenshot of my android studio if can be helpful
[image]

Comment: Please show your app level `gradle.build`. Take time to take the [stackoverflow.com/tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) with reference on how to ask a question.

Comment: I am facing same issue @Kevinddn99. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any solution?

Comment: have anyone solved this error?

Answer (score 12):

Most likely, you have NDK r17 installed, which does not support **armeabi** anymore. Your gradle plugin is not aware of this recent change. You must upgrade: in **build.gradle**, you should have

```
buildscript { dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
} }
```

and in **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

But even after upgrade, your **build.gradle** most likely lacks the **abiFilters** statement, and therefore your project build is slower and APK larger than necessary.

You probably only need on ABI in your APK,

```
android { defaultConfig { ndk {
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
} } }
```

Comment: I still get the error, I tried and with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'` and nothing changed.

Comment: @AdrianBuciuman note that `Build command failed` may have wide variety of causes with ndkBuild, not necessarily related to non-matching versions of NDK and Grade plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error recently - the cause was a mystery and still is. I reinstalled everything, but I could not get my project to Clean.

In the end I manually deleted the `app/build` and `app/.externalNativeBuild` folders, and the project rebuilt fine, and I was then able to run Clean without errors again.