# React native android build fails with NDK error

Tags: android-ndk, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I am using appcenter for CI of my react native projects. The CI build is failing for me with the error

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 
':app:transformNative_libsWithStripDebugSymbolForDevDebug'.
A problem occurred starting process 'command 
'/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mipsel-linux- 
android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/mipsel-linux-android-strip''
```

The issue seems to be due to updgration of android NDK to r17 (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19321).

I have tried to remove the armeabi from my NDK and apk splits configuration.

The NDK configuration is

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "<name>"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "x86"
    }
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

The splits configuration is

```
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "x86"
    }
}


applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

The build is still not working.

Any workarounds will be greatly helpful.

Comment: I hope https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345736/192373 will help you. TL;NR: upgrade the Gradle plugin

Comment: @AlexCohn, thanks upgrading the plugin and following the migration path fixed the issue