# How remove libgnustl_static.a at linking when compiling apk with native code using Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, ninja

I am using Android Studio (3.4.1) to build an apk that contains a C++ part. The compile phase works, and the link phase throw an error.

**The error :**

> **clang++: error**: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/homefolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/**gnu-libstdc++**/4.9/libs/x86/libgnustl_static.a'

This comes from the last line of the full link command :

> /Users/homefolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++
>   --target=i686-none-linux-android23 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/homefolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
>   --sysroot=/Users/homefolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot
>   -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O2 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libmy_lib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/x86/libmy_lib.so
>   CMakeFiles/my_lib.dir/src/main/cpp/my_lib.cpp.o 
>   -llog ../../../../libs/x86/libssl.a ../../../../libs/x86/libcrypto.a -latomic -lm **"/Users/homefolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/libgnustl_static.a**"

Indeed this library does not exist in my sdk folder. The folder `gnu-lib-stdc++`does not exists.

As far as I understand, the native code is compiled with CMake. CMake generates build.ninja files and executes ninja to compile. If I modify manually these generated build.ninja files **to remove this library** and then call `ninja` in the terminal (in the correct folder), then it compiles and links perfectly.

**The problem :**

Where should I modify the Android Studio settings so these build.ninja files do not contain this library anymore? I don't want to modify the generated files each time I produce an apk.

**What I have tried so far :**

The only parameter file I found related to CMake is `CMakeList.txt`. And from documentation ([1](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/variable/CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE.html)) , it seems like this library can be set up using `CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE`. I have put this to `'none'` or `'system'` in `CMakeList.txt`, but I see no difference in the build.ninja files.

```
# CMakeList.txt
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE none)
```

**Configuration :**

- Android Studio 3.4.1
- Android SDK Tools 26.1.1
- CMake 3.10.2 (not sure,
  3.6 also installed)
- macOS 10.14

Comment: The title "How remove the default math library ..."  doesn't reflect the problem: the problem is entirely about `libgnustl_static.a` library. Not sure why you have highlighed `-lm` in the link command. The proper name of the *variable* you use is [CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/variable/CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE.html), `ANDROID_STL_TYPE` is a *property* name, for which `set()` doesn't work. Also be sure, that you `set()` the variable **before** the `add_library` call in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Does "-lm" mean to link with the math library, and the following path is the link to that library ? To my understanding this is the whole option I am looking to remove. Is it not ?

Comment: No, `-lm` is a **separate** option for link with a math library. The last argument in double quotes is a **separate** option too, and it also means linking. Difference between last two options is that `-l` flag asks linker to **search** the library. Without `-l` the linkers just uses the path which is passed.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you. I will modify the subject. Yet, I tried many values for the `set()`, before the `add_library` call, and the build.file does not change at all. It is like my `set()` has no effect.

Comment: You also have NDK installed, check it in SDK Manager. The problem, probably, comes from the Android grade plugin version, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345736/192373) case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And from documentation (1) , it seems like this library can be set up using CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE. I have put this to 'none' or 'system' in CMakeList.txt, but I see no difference in the build.ninja files.
>
> ```
> # CMakeList.txt
> set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE none)
> ```

Wrong documentation. You want https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake. Set the following value in your build.gradle:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
      cmake {
        arguments "-DANDROID_STL=none",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After further research thanks to Tsyvarev comments, I found the solution: I modified manually all `CMakeCache.txt` files in the `.ExternalNativeBuild` folder.

Before :

```
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES:STRING=-latomic -lm "/Users/homefolder/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a"
```

Manual fix :

```
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES:STRING=-latomic -lm
```

Then, the auto-generated build.ninja files do not contain the link to libgnustl_static.a anymore. And the apk compiles.

This fix does not make send to me. I though that all files in `.ExternalNativeBuild` are auto-generated and erased at each new build. The name itself has `cache` in it, so it does not sounds like a file a user should modify. Yet it was the working solution to my problem.

I believe it is these `CCMakeCaches.txt` files are generated at the first build, and then re-used for the following build requests. This is very not logical to me. I do not understand why `set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE none)` did not work.